# Export a table in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have generated a table with the powers of 2 and their logarithm in base 2 in the following way:

```
import math
x = 2.0
while x < 100.0:
    print x, '\t', math.log(x)/math.log(2)
    x = x + x
```

How can I export this table in a CSV file with each element that matches exactly one cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer

```
import math
import csv

x = 2.0
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    while x < 100.0:
        print x, '\t', math.log(x)/math.log(2)
        writer.writerow([x, math.log(x)/math.log(2)])
        x = x + x
```

Comment: Following you example, the data is stored in only one column... I need to write the data in separate cells!

Comment: you can change delimiter in python or in Excel but they should be the same